# building execute m-file + simulink model (I have a program with one error!)

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have been written a program with MATLAB:

1. clear all; clc
2. load  data.dat
3. a=data+2;
4. b=fun(a);
5. sim(‘new_equ2’)
6. c=b+A;
7. save  new_data  c  -ascii

--> my program has been saved by name “test.m”

In line 4:   ‘fun’ is a function.

In line 5: ‘new_equ2’ is a simulink model.

In line 6: ‘A’ is  simulink model output.

I wanted to build execute file from test.m, therefore i wrote in command window:

> > mcc  -m  test

After that, i ran test.exe in windows command prompt. I encountered with this error:

“Undefined function or method ‘sim’ . . . “

I want to create execute file from test.m that it runs without error.

Comment: Hi, you can motivate people to answer by removing your spelling errors (title!) and generally choosing a better title. Also have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Simulink, including the sim command, is not supported by MATLAB Compiler.

[Ineligible Programs with MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/ineligible_programs/index.html)